# Redirect all routes who starts with a specified word to homepage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, php-5.3

I have a problem with my .htaccess. My file .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/paiement
RewriteRule .* /index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/paiement/test1/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/paiement/test2/dfd/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/paiement/test3/lkjjk [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/paiement/test4/fdf/fdfd/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /another/$1 [QSA,L
```

So I want to redirect all routes who starts with /paiement to index.php.
Help me please. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found the solution, it's necessaire to make a redirect to root, like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/paiement
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
```